# Can analytic functions add or remove rows from a resultset?

Tags: oracle, select, window-functions, oracle-19c, row

I'm a novice who is starting to learn about Oracle analytic functions (window functions).

I know from experience that it's important to ***fully*** understand how SQL mechanisms work when using them in queries. It can be extremely easy to make mistakes and produce incorrect results.

For example, a left join can propagate-out duplicate rows, if the relationship was 1:M, but the person writing the query didn't realize it. And for non-experts, GROUP BY can produce unexpected row counts, etc.

---

Question:

Are there any scenarios where analytic functions can add or remove rows from a resultset? Or can I safely assume that analytic functions only provide additional information as calculated columns -- and don't ever effect the row count?

Comment: [Order of a SQL Query](https://dataschool.com/sql-optimization/order-of-a-sql-query/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer seems to be no.

- Window functions only add additional information to the resultset as an extra column. They don't ever add or remove rows from the resultset.

---

Source:

> PluralSight course: [Advanced SQL Queries in Oracle and SQL Server](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/adv-sql-queries-oracle-sql-server/table-of-contents) *by Scott Hecht*
>
> **What are Analytic Functions:**
>
> - The resulting row count is the same as the incoming row count.
> - Last SQL operation performed.
> - Performed on the results of the query.
> - Not affected by GROUP BY, HAVING, or WHERE
>
> [Slide 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgRnh.png) |
> [Slide 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YlAT.png)

*I would recommend [that course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/adv-sql-queries-oracle-sql-server/table-of-contents) to anyone who wants to learn more about Analytic Functions and other advanced SQL querying topics.*